# Difference between "Thru" and "Through"

Tags: word-choice, difference

I can't figure out what the difference between *thru* and *through* is. I'm working on a text for a website. I described some process and used this sentence:

> [...] when guiding the user **through** the order process.

Is that correct, or should I instead use the following sentence?

> [...] when guiding the user **thru** the order process.

Comment: Use `through` in that context. In formal contexts, `thru` should be reserved for where space is at a premium, like on a street sign, or perhaps in a newspaper headline. More good reading on this subject can be found on [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91778/thru-vs-through).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Thru* and *through* are different spellings of the same word, although *through* is widely accepted as the more "normal" spelling:

The following NGram from the American English corpus, shows that even in US English, *through* has always been vastly more popular than *thru*.

[image]

Note that in British English, *thru* is widely considered incorrect, although it is a common shorthand for *through* in text messaging and instant messaging.

So in summary, when you see *thru* written, read it as *through*, but you should try to avoid using *thru* yourself except in very informal messaging with friends, as it is less popular, less formal and less widely accepted than *through* and you can always replace *thru* with *through* without loss of meaning.

Comment: +1. *Thru* is incorrect in AmE as well, though when used as shorthand in informal situations it is equally well understood. The only situation I'm aware of where "thru" is a popular/accepted spelling is in "drive-thru" (though that can be also written "drive-through").

Comment: @WendiKidd: I'm not sure about "incorrect" - certainly it's less than formal (OED lists it as a word but notes it is "chiefly North American"). I've seen people write of having "meetings 9 thru 5" and write "a contract running from Jun 1st thru August 17th", but only ever on the US side of the pond.

Comment: http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/thru

Answer (score 0):

*Through* and *thru* have the same meaning. They even sound the same. *Thru* is just a shortened version of *through*. The same way that you can, informally, use *r* instead of *are*.

Comment: Egads! I know what you're saying, but I don't see them on quite the same plane. While it's common to see [THRU](http://www.google.com/search?q=no+thru+traffic&safe=active&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=5xLvUaGqJJbb4AOOq4HgDQ&sqi=2&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1571&bih=909) on street signs, I hope I never see a highway sign reading `U R LEAVING COOK COUNTY` or the like.

Answer (score 0):

*Thru* is merely an informal spelling of *through*, in the same way *gas* is a North American informal short for *gasoline*.

As the *Oxford Dictionary of English, 3rd edition* says, *thru* is chiefly North American.

Comment: It's definitely an Americanism.

Comment: kiam, I'm not sure the parallel whit "gasoline" works. In fact, if you trim "gasoline" removing "oline" at the very end a word remain "gas"; but it is not the same for "through" because, I guess, "thru" means noting alone.

Comment: The parallelism is that both _thru_ and _gas_ are informal and North American English.

Comment: *Thru* is less acceptable than *gas* in most writing.

Answer (score 0):

*Thru* is a variant spelling of *through* and, according to B.A. Garner, *A Dictionary of Modern American Usage*, it "should  be shunned", even if it appears on street signs (NO THRU ROAD).

[image]

Comment: Signs often use abbreviations because it allows the letters to be bigger, and visibility and speed of reading is more important on signage for safety reasons than correct spelling or grammar. In the US we even have English-atrocities such as "Ped Xing" as shorthand for "Pedestrian Crossing" (http://www.mathpropress.com/stan/crossings/CrossingSigns/PedXing2FacingLeft.jpg), but once you've worked out what it means, it's faster to read at a distance (although I prefer the UK system of just having a picture).